# ExceptionLogger not logging in release mode but works in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

I have a Web API that uses a global `ExceptionLogger` which works well in debug however no exceptions are being logged in release. I have also instantiated a new `FileTraceListener` as shown below:

```
public class LogException : ExceptionLogger
{
    private FileTraceListener _traceListener;

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        _traceListener = new FileTraceListener(
            "yyyy-MM-dd",
            ".txt",
            "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss fff",
            "C:\\logs\\API",
            "5");

        //Log Critical errors
        Exception ex = context.Exception;
        _traceListener.LogException(ex);
    }
}
```

This is also registered in the `WebApiConfig` as so:

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new LogException());
```

I have a `ITraceWriter` that works well in both release and debug already. How can I narrow down the problem since I am unable to debug the release mode. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to clean and then rebuild, let me know if it works

Comment: @Nehorai Tried this, unfortunately no changes.

Comment: Do you have the related dll on release also?

Comment: @Nehorai Yes, when I build in release I can see the relevant dll in the bin folder.